# android ratingbar scaled weird

Tags: android, scale, native, ratingbar

In my android project I want to inculde a RatingBar. But it always Looks like this

[image]

My XML inculdes the following Code

```
<RatingBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/dogsMotivationRatingBar"
                android:layout_below="@+id/trainingAccomplishedHintText"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:rating="3"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.RatingBar" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/dogs_motivation_hint"
                android:id="@+id/dogsMotivationHintText"
                android:layout_below="@+id/dogsMotivationRatingBar"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Could anyone Help me?

Comment: Curious: why did you `alignParentLeft="true"`, but `alignParentStart="false"`?

Comment: post your whole layout xml

Comment: Did you got solution, i am facing this issue too

Comment: Facing this issue too. Just on Samsung Galaxy Tab 3.

Answer (score 0):

Either remove

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

or

```
  android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Set **indeterminateOnly** to false.

```
android:indeterminateOnly="false"
```